# Paypal not picking up selection choices

Tags: javascript, paypal

I have created a script for partial season ticket package sales on my music group's website. A user would select 4 concert programs and then select a date for each concert program selected. All of these selections need to post to Paypal for processing/purchasing. My "Add to Cart" button does route to Paypal, but the concert programs and dates are not being picked up. The box office people need this information. You can see the code I have here: http://jsfiddle.net/saraswati/v6Pur/66/

Here is the HTML:

```
<form target="paypal" action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post"><strong><a name="Partial">Partial</a> subscription (4 concerts), Regular Price: $87.00 (a savings of 13%)</strong>
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart">
<input type="hidden" name="add" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="temp_1344946752_biz@me.com">
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Partial subscription (4 concerts), Regular Price">
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="87.00">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">

<table width="90%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="1">
<CAPTION>Please select the desired concert program and then the desired date from the pull-down menus. Then click the "Add to Cart" button.</CAPTION>

<tr id="row1" align=center>
<td><font color="#990000">Concert 1:</font></td>
<td><font color="#990000">Concert 2:</font></td>
<td><font color="#990000">Concert 3:</font></td>
<td><font color="#990000">Concert 4:</font></td>
</tr>
<tr id=row2>
<td><input type="hidden" name="os0" value="Concert 1"><body onload="ChangeDateDropList ();">   
    <select id="program1" onchange="ChangeDateDropList(1);"> 
        <option value="" selected="selected">Select a Program</option> 
        <option value="TUDORS">The Tudors</option> 
        <option value="NOCHES">Noches, Noches</option> 
        <option value="CHRISTMAS">Christmas Eurotour</option> 
        <option value="CELTIC">Celtic Trinity</option>
        <option value="UNREQUITED">Unrequited Love</option>
        <option value="SECRET">Secret No More</option> 
    </select> 

    <select id="date1"> 
    </select> 
</body>
</td>

<td><input type="hidden" name="os1" value="Concert 2"><body onload="ChangeDateDropList ();">   
    <select id="program2" onchange="ChangeDateDropList(2);"> 
        <option value="" selected="selected">Select a Program</option> 
        <option value="TUDORS">The Tudors</option> 
        <option value="NOCHES">Noches, Noches</option> 
        <option value="CHRISTMAS">Christmas Eurotour</option> 
        <option value="CELTIC">Celtic Trinity</option>
        <option value="UNREQUITED">Unrequited Love</option>
        <option value="SECRET">Secret No More</option> 
    </select> 

    <select id="date2"> 
    </select>
</body> 
</td>

<td><input type="hidden" name="os2" value="Concert 3"><body onload="ChangeDateDropList ();">   
    <select id="program3" onchange="ChangeDateDropList(3);"> 
        <option value="" selected="selected">Select a Program</option> 
        <option value="TUDORS">The Tudors</option> 
        <option value="NOCHES">Noches, Noches</option> 
        <option value="CHRISTMAS">Christmas Eurotour</option> 
        <option value="CELTIC">Celtic Trinity</option>
        <option value="UNREQUITED">Unrequited Love</option>
        <option value="SECRET">Secret No More</option> 
    </select> 

    <select id="date3"> 
    </select> 
</body>
</td>

<td><input type="hidden" name="os3" value="Concert 4"><body onload="ChangeDateDropList ();">   
    <select id="program4" onchange="ChangeDateDropList(4);"> 
        <option value="" selected="selected">Select a Program</option> 
        <option value="TUDORS">The Tudors</option> 
        <option value="NOCHES">Noches, Noches</option> 
        <option value="CHRISTMAS">Christmas Eurotour</option> 
        <option value="CELTIC">Celtic Trinity</option>
        <option value="UNREQUITED">Unrequited Love</option>
        <option value="SECRET">Secret No More</option> 
    </select> 

    <select id="date4"> 
    </select> 
</body>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
<br>
<center>
<input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_cart_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>
</center>
```

And here is the Javascript:

```
 var progamsAndDates = {};
    progamsAndDates.TUDORS = ['Sept. 15', 'Sept. 16'];
    progamsAndDates.NOCHES = ['Oct. 20', 'Oct. 21'];
    progamsAndDates.CHRISTMAS = ['Dec. 14', 'Dec. 15', 'Dec. 16'];
    progamsAndDates.CELTIC = ['Jan. 26', 'Jan. 27'];
    progamsAndDates.UNREQUITED = ['Mar. 02', 'Mar. 03'];
    progamsAndDates.SECRET = ['Apr. 20', 'Apr. 21'];

    function ChangeDateDropList (id) { 

        var programDropList = document.getElementById ("program"+id);
        var dateDropList = document.getElementById ("date"+id);
        var selProgram = programDropList.options[programDropList.selectedIndex].value;

        // remove all dates
        while (dateDropList.options.length) {
            dateDropList.remove (0);
        }

        // add new dates
        var dates = progamsAndDates[selProgram];
        if (dates) {
            for (var i=0; i < dates.length; i++) {
                var date = new Option (dates[i], i);
                dateDropList.options.add (date);
            }
        }
    }
```

Again, when I click on the "Add to Cart" button, it goes to Paypal and the description reads "Partial subscription (4 concerts), Regular Price" and it picks up the Item Price, etc. However, the description should also show the selections, such as "Tudors, Sept. 15; Celtic, Jan.27; etc." I query the wisdom of you all in getting this to work. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The variables you are passing over are not correct.  You are passing over variables such as on0, os0, on1, os1.  These would be correct for add to cart buttons or buy now buttons, but since you are using the cart upload method they need to be passed over like on0_1, os0_1, on1_2, and os1_2.  This will correct your issue, and they should then show up.

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart">
<input type="hidden" name="upload" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="my_email@my_site.com">

<input type="hidden" name="item_name_1" value="Football T-Shirt">
<input type="hidden" name="amount_1" value="1.00">
<input type="hidden" name="on0_1" value="Color">
<input type="hidden" name="os0_1" value="Red">
<input type="hidden" name="on1_1" value="Size">
<input type="hidden" name="os1_1" value="Small">

<input type="hidden" name="item_name_2" value="Notebook">
<input type="hidden" name="amount_2" value="2.00">
<input type="hidden" name="on0_2" value="Number of Pages">
<input type="hidden" name="os0_2" value="200">
<input type="hidden" name="on1_2" value="Type">
<input type="hidden" name="os1_2" value="3 Ring">

<input type="submit" value="PayPal">
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! I will try to correct the variables as you suggest and, fingers crossed, it will work. Thank you!

Comment: Back again. I tried to do as you suggested, but I guess I don't understand how to do this.  Currently I have "os0," "os1," "os2," and "os3".  So, I changed them to "os0_1," "os1_2," "os2_3," and "os3_4". I tried my script again with these changes and clicked on "Add to Cart." Again, it took me to the Paypal page, but didn't pick up my selections. Apologies for my misunderstanding! If you have time, could you explain what I have done wrong? Thank you!

Comment: Please see my edited answer, I added an example of what I was referring to.

Comment: Thank you, @PP_MTS_Chad, for your updated example. I will try that and hope I can get this to coordinate with my JavaScript. Thank you very much!

Comment: I'm afraid I am still not able to get this to work. If you have time, could you please have a look at my updated "jsfiddle" page: < http://jsfiddle.net/saraswati/v6Pur/75/ >.  My situation seems a bit more complex, and I've tried various numbering schemes and I still can't get Paypal to pick up any of the concert programs and dates. Thank you very much for your time and expertise!

Comment: I apologize, going back and looking at your code again, you were not using the cart upload method but rather just one add to cart button that was adding all 4 items together instead of passing them over separately.  In this case you were correct in what you were doing, you would want to use the the variables on0,os0,on1,os1,on2,os2 and etc.  Make sure they are used in order and in the pairs such as onx and osx.  if this still isn't working, I will try creating a working example for you.

Comment: Thanks so much for having a look again. It seems rather confusing, but yes, users need to select 4 concert programs and each program as 2 or 3 choices for dates. Users select their 4 programs and desired date for each program, and then there is one "Add to Cart" button to add all 4 of these selections together. In my original code (when submitting my original query), I had "os0" with "Concert 1," "os1" for "Concert 2," etc.  I didn't have any "onx" values and I'm not sure where they would go now. ?  If you could please help with a working example, I would be ever so grateful!

Comment: BTW, on the shopping cart page, I'd like for the selected options to appear in the format "ConcertX: ProgramName, Date;" such as the following example: "Concert 1: Noches, Oct. 21; Concert 2: Christmas, Dec. 16; Concert 3: Unrequited: Mar. 02; Concert 4: Secret: Apr. 21." But, I can't even get the coding set so that it picks up the user's selections. Again, if you could please help with a working example, I would be so grateful!