# unable to pass the drop down values to Paypal

Tags: paypal

Here is a little html that is supposed to send product information (number of units, size and color of two products) out to Paypal. The units, and size get through to Paypal, but for some reason the drop down menus with the color do not. Can anybody see an error in my code?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title> Order Test Product</title>
<meta name="verify-v1" content="n3Dpx4NklZjg5p/Tq7h1q+Oj6Ml83crtkO/PwepVQ6Y=" />
<meta http-equiv="imagetoolbar" content="no" />
<meta name= "robots" content="index,nofollow" />
</head>
<body>
<h1> Order your footwear here </h1>
<h2> Select your size, colour and quantity desired, then click PAY NOW </h2>

<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">

<table width="80%" border="1" align="center">

<tr><th>Product</th><th>Color</th><th>Quantity</th><th width="90">Not Ordeed</th><th>Size Small</th><th>Size Medium</th><th>Size Large</th></tr>

<tr><th> Shoes</th>
<td>    <input type="hidden" name="on1" value="color" />
<select name="os1">
<option value="---">Select Color </option>
<option value="brown-shoes">Brown </option>
<option value="black-shoes">Black </option>
<option value="White-shoes">White </option>
</select></td>

<td><input type="text" size="2" maxlength="3" name="quantity_1" /></td>
<td><label>
<input type="radio" name="amount_1" value="0" checked="checked" /></label></td>
<td title="&euro;7"><label>
<input type="radio" name="amount_1" value="7" />
</label></td>

<td title="&euro;10"><label>
<input type="radio" name="amount_1" value="10" /></label></td>
<td title="&euro;13"><label>
<input type="radio" name="amount_1" value="13" /></label></td> 
</tr>

<tr>
<th>Boots</th>
<td><input type="hidden" name="on2" value="color" />
<select name="os2">
<option value="---">Select Color </option>
<option value="brown-boots">Brown </option>
<option value="black-boots">Black </option>
<option value="White-boots">White </option>
</select></td>    

<td><input type="text" size="2" maxlength="3" name="quantity_2" /><br /></td>
<td><label>
<input type="radio" name="amount_2" value="0" checked="checked" />
</label><br /><br /></td>
<td title="&euro;15"><label>
<input type="radio" name="amount_2" value="15" />
</label></td>

<td title="&euro;20"><label>
<input type="radio" name="amount_2" value="20" />
</label></td>
<td title="&euro;25"><label>
<input type="radio" name="amount_2" value="25" />
</label></td>
</tr>
</table>

<br /><br />
<input type="image" src="../eStore/paynow.jpg"  name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online." />
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypal.com/en_GB/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1" />

<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart" />
<input type="hidden" name="upload" value="1" />
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="info@kalikalos.com" />
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="EUR" />

<input type="hidden" name="item_name_1" value="Shoes" />
<input type="hidden" name="item_name_2" value="Boots" />

</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: may the backend (php?) is not recovering the value of the color?

Comment: Sorry, I don't follow you. What "backend php"? Normally with a drop down menu in the form the value is transmitted directly to Paypal. on1 and os1 are normally all the key's that tell Paypal to pick up the values.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to [Paypal not picking up selection choices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15837174/paypal-not-picking-up-selection-choices), you need to change the code:

```html
<tr><th> Shoes</th>
<td>    <input type="hidden" name="on0_1" value="color" />
<select name="os0_1">
<option value="---">Select Color </option>
<option value="brown-shoes">Brown </option>
<option value="black-shoes">Black </option>
<option value="White-shoes">White </option>
</select></td>
.....
<tr>
<th>Boots</th>
<td><input type="hidden" name="on0_2" value="color" />
<select name="os0_2">
<option value="---">Select Color </option>
<option value="brown-boots">Brown </option>
<option value="black-boots">Black </option>
<option value="White-boots">White </option>
</select></td>
```

Comment: I thought it was working fine. It certainy did work once, but now it is no longer passing the color. Can you have a look at http://www.kalikalos.com/eStore/book-product.html to see if I have still got something wrong in there?

Comment: Now it is working again! Must be a browser problem, the code seems fine.

Comment: Now, I added a third item (socks) to my products list and the code no longer works for either boots or socks. What am I doing wrong? I would like to show the code changes but there seems to be no way for me to attach my code as there was for my original question. Do I need to create a new question?